# Как запустить плейбук ansible непривелигированному пользователю?

Tags: ansible

При выполнении плейбука, на удаленном хосте пользователь не имеет доступа к `/bin/sh` и `/usr/bin/python`.

Как изменить способ подключения ansible к хосту без `'/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -u root /bin/sh -c`?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы Ansible не использовал `sudo`, не нужно указывать директивы `become` (ранее `sudo`) в плейбуке/инвентаре.

Для замены интерпретаторов и/или пути к ним можно использовать переменные хостов (host vars):

- `ansible_shell_executable` – для оболочки
- `ansible_python_interpreter` – для Python

Comment: ansible_shell_executable можно изменить только для модулей с выполнением команд?

Comment: это глобальный параметр – Ansible будет все модули через shell, указанный в этом параметре запускать.

Comment: Как изменить эту переменную, если выполняется плейбук? Т.е. в connection/__init.py менять?
 ansible-playbook -i host, /etc/ansible/priv.yml -u user --private-key=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -vvv

Comment: Добавить в inventory, или запускать с указанием переменной окружения `ANSIBLE_EXECUTABLE=/bin/bash ansible-playbook ....`

Comment: /bin/bash удаленному пользователю так же не разрешен.

Comment: Укажите оболочку, которая разрешена.

Comment: Без оболочки ansible бук не выполнится?