# Как работает sudo в ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает sudo в ansible и в чем его разница, если я применяю sudo непосредственно в консоли,
Авторизованным на сервере, в консоли выполняю

```
[user@server01 opt]$ sudo mkdir /opt/test
```

Выполняется успешно, но при использовании команды непосредственно с помощью ansible:

```
[user@server01 opt]$ ansible servers -m file -a "dest=/opt/test  mode=755" -k -u user -b
```

Возникает ошибка

```
"module_stdout": "Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qvlcsrrsgixvikeamiollrbbnyxljoxl
```

Используется стандартные become настройки, включая метод, sudo.
У меня и в самом деле ограниченный sudo на команды /bin/sh и /bin/bash, вопрос заключается в следующем, в чем разница моего локального выполнения sudo и через ansible, почему ansible под пользователем на конечном сервере пытается выполнить не sudo **mkdir /opt/test**, а как понимаю **sudo /bin/sh mkdir /opt/test**, в следствии чего возникает ошибка *is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh mkdir /opt/test' as root*?

### права sudo -l

```
(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/sh, !/bin/tcsh, !/bin/csh, !/bin/zsh, !/bin/ksh, !/bin/bash, !/usr/bin/sudo, !/bin/su, !/usr/bin/mc
(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
(root) NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/sh, !/bin/tcsh, !/bin/csh, !/bin/zsh, !/bin/ksh, !/bin/bash, !/usr/bin/sudo, !/bin/su, !/usr/bin/mc, !/usr/bin/chattr, !/usr/bin/screen, !/usr/bin/tmux
```

P.S. коллеги, если убрать из запретов !/bin/sh и !/bin/bash, то конечно будет работать и аналогичный вопрос конечно уже был, но может с 17 года появились ответы, [Как запустить плейбук ansible непривелигированному пользователю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682578/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA-ansible-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E?rq=1)

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#id9

Answer (score 1):

О-о-о, помню эту фигню.  Суть в том, что *Ansible* перед тем, как
выполнить собственно команду, зачем-то проверяет, можно ли вообще
использовать `sudo`.  И делает он это через `/bin/sh -c
echo …`.  И если этот `echo` не удаётся, он считает,
что `sudo` не `sudo`.  И это почти нигде не
документировано!

У меня была ситуация, где sudo разрешалось использовать одну-две
команды, и никакого /bin/sh.  Я с этим часа два боролся, а потом плюнул
и решил просто прописать `sudo` внутри команды текстом и не
использовать этот их сломанный, слишком «умный» `become`
вовсе.  Возможно, придёт другой коллега и покажет класс, но для меня
ответ был простой: «Это сломано».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, если использовать внутри команды, то все работает как часы.
Если разрешить "/bin/sh -c
echo", но запретить остальные команды с /bin/sh, поможет ли это?

Comment: Думаю да, может помочь.  Сам не проверял.